# teradata converting timestamp to time

Tags: sql, time, timestamp, teradata

I'm struggling with something that seems very obvious on first sight and most probably I'm overlooking something stupid but anyway.
I need to calculate the difference between timestamp fields and convert the result (which is as I  assume a timestamp ) into the number of days and the elapsed time.
I can't seem to get the cast(xx to time) wright

I made a small example

```
SELECT  
    Cast(Cast( c_date AS CHAR(10)) || ' ' || Cast( c_time AS CHAR(10)) AS TIMESTAMP(6)) AS starttime ,
    Cast(Cast( e_date AS CHAR(10)) || ' ' || Cast( e_time AS CHAR(10)) AS TIMESTAMP(6)) AS endtm,
    (endtm - starttime) DAY(4) TO SECOND AS difftime
    ,Extract(DAY From difftime)  --> gives the days 
    ,Cast(difftime AS TIME)
    ,Extract (HOUR From difftime) 
FROM    (
            SELECT  Cast(Current_Timestamp AS DATE) c_date, 
                    Cast(Current_Timestamp(0) AS TIME(0)) c_time,
                    Cast(Current_Timestamp + Random(1,10) * INTERVAL '1' DAY AS DATE) e_date,
                    Cast(Current_Timestamp(0) + Random(1,24) * INTERVAL '1' HOUR + Random(1,60) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE AS TIME(0)) e_time
        ) t
```

,Cast(difftime AS TIME) gives me the trouble
the extract day and hour works => the difftime is really a timestamp (is it ? and if not what kind of field is it then ? ).

some advise would be nice :-)

Comment: The difference between time zones is an interval of time, not itself a timezone. However, if it's the same UTC time in two locations, you might just end up getting zero, since teradata might convert timezones. I'm not sure your current approach is the best one.

Comment: Your question is really unclear.  I don't see anything about timezones.  Please add sample data and desired result.  Also, how your timestamp column(s) are defined in the DDL (timestamp, timestamp with tz).

Comment: `(endtm - starttime) DAY(4) TO SECOND` **is** *number of days and the elapsed time*, but in a single column.  If you want to split it into two columns: `Extract(DAY From difftime) AS num_days, Cast(difftime - (num_days * INTERVAL '1' DAY) AS INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND)`

Comment: So, the result is what as fieldtype ?  Since you can use functions like extract(day ... ), difftime - (num_days * INTERVAL '1' DAY) AS INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND I suppose it is a timestamp field or not ?
Anyhow, the solution of dnoeth works but I would still like to understand how this works internally in teradata.  What kind of field do you get if you subtract 2 timestamp fields ?

Comment: @dnoeth I would like to mark your post as the correct answer but, I don't seem to find how todo so.  I only seem able to "flag it for serious problems or moderator attention"
Anyhow, I ran a small test to answer my question about the datatype for the new field.
Just did a "create table as ... )

Comment: This is the result
´show TABLE s0_sdb_cop.test_on_type_of_field;

CREATE SET TABLE s0_sdb_cop.test_on_type_of_field ,NO FALLBACK ,
NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
NO AFTER JOURNAL,
CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
(
starttime TIMESTAMP(6),
endtm TIMESTAMP(6),
difftime INTERVAL DAY(4) TO SECOND(6),
diff_days INTEGER,
num_days INTEGER,
elapsed_time INTERVAL HOUR(2) TO SECOND(6),
diff_time_in_seconds DECIMAL(18,6))
PRIMARY INDEX ( starttime );

So, the datatype is an interval and so it's completely logic I cannot convert to time.

Comment: You define the resulting interval type of the difference between timestamps as part of the calculation: `(endtm - starttime) DAY(4) TO SECOND` (btw, `TYPE((endtm - starttime) DAY(4) TO SECOND)` will reveal it without creating a table). EXTRACT works on any datetime and interval data type. What data type do you want/need?

Comment: I do not need a certain datatype. An interval is fine for me but, as I expected that a timestamp - a timestamp would be a timestamp, I just did not understand why I could not cast this into a TIME.  Knowing now that it's an interval clarify's this and reveals also the things I'm able to do with this field.  ( also thanks for the TYPE command, didn't know that either)

Comment: The difference between 10 AM and 8 AM is two hours, not 2 AM :-) Intervals are confusing because the are formatted like a datetime.